# Error 1054 in MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following query:

```
    $query="SELECT language_value, votes, user_id FROM labels WHERE approved=1 AND label_value=".
            $data[$i]['label_value']." AND language=".$language_id;
```

I have got the error:

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'AccountPagesView.a_book' in 'where clause'
```

But 'AccountPagesView.a_book' is value of $data[$i]['label_value'] and isn't a column. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: instead of running query in mysql_query() first echo this query as a string in then copy it  then run it in mysql yog or any sql gui to see how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enclose any string values in MySQL in `'`:

```
$query= "SELECT language_value, votes, user_id FROM labels WHERE approved=1 AND label_value='".
        $data[$i]['label_value']."' AND language='".$language_id."'";
```

(I just took a guess, which are string-like columns.)

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @vstm: make sure the the values, you insert here, are properly escaped.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion as well. Can't see anything else too obvious in the query.

Comment: If you use that solution, please don't forget to **properly escape** the values that are inserted to the query!

Comment: I have added that you suggested me, but it doesn't work properly. So, please, tell me, how can I escape the values?

Comment: @user1477886 Depends on your actual commands, to issue the query. I think, you will need `mysql_escape_string()`([Docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)). But you should take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query="SELECT language_value, votes, user_id FROM labels WHERE approved=1 AND label_value='".$data[$i]['label_value']."' AND language='".$language_id."'";
```